# Node reference solution for a content type which referenced to two fields. (company, product & review)

Tags: nodes, entities

My website has three content types: company, product & review.

1). The product has a field referenced to a company node using Node URL Reference module.

2). The review has two fields, one referenced to company node, another referenced to product node.

The question is how to implement the item 2) following the behaviours described below:

1. While creating review node from company node, the product field should be updated to the products which belongs to that company.
2. While creating a review from product node, the company & product fields should be auto-filled.

Could you help me? I research this issue for several days but haven't resolved completely. Thanks a lot.

Comment: did you take look at Node URL Reference module read me? Check the section under 'Advanced: Build your own links'

Comment: How are you creating the review node from the company node?

Answer (score 0):

Try [entityreference_prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate)

This will allow you to create a link with query string to pre-fill selections on an entity reference form field.